# Mysql query where one datavalue matches 2 columns of table

Tags: mysql, sql

I escape all my inputs using the traditional string then array format. so:

```
'WHERE VALUE1 LIKE ? AND VALUE2 LIKE ?', ['%abba%', 'Rob%']
```

I need to throw in an "OR" into the statement to have the first DataValue searched for in two Columns....

```
'WHERE (VALUE1 LIKE ? OR VALUE2 LIKE ?) AND VALUE3 LIKE ?', ['%abba%', '%abba%', 'Rob%']
```

However the dataValuesArray is ['%abba%', 'Rob%'], 
Without modifying the dataValues Array, Is there a way I can search across 2 Columns with one value something like this:
(this is not real code)

```
'WHERE (VALUE1 OR VALUE2 LIKE ?) AND VALUE3 LIKE ?', ['%abba%', 'Rob%']
```

There are other ways around this, just wondering if it can be done in mysql.

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: your pseudo code `'WHERE (VALUE1 LIKE ? OR VALUE2 LIKE ?) AND VALUE3 LIKE ?', ['%abba%', '%abba%', 'Rob%']` just need braces to become valid

Comment: Thanks fixed. I know that works but Not what I'm asking

Comment: just as a trick you can try `WHERE ? IN (VALUE1, VALUE2)`

Comment: Would that work with wildcards?

Comment: Put your comments in an answer And I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best answer but just a trick that can help in some cases.

We can compare parameter using `IN` against several columns :

`WHERE ? IN (VALUE1, VALUE2)`